# Heroku cedar: slower response time than bamboo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stack, bamboo

I've a rails 3 app, running well/fast on herokus bamboo stack. 
To test whether my app works on the upcoming cedar stack, I've deployed it to heroku, following the "getting started" guide. To my surprise, everything works well and without an error. The only difference I've noticed: the response time is quite a bit slower compared to the app running on the bamboo stack. Tests with unicorn instead of thin showed no differences.

Have you noticed roughly the same difference between the both stacks?

Answer (score 6):

Varnish cache changed on cedar stack ... have a look at how you're caching 
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching ...

```
Varnish is not available on Cedar. 
Use rack-cache and the memcache add-on for in-app caching instead. 
See HTTP routing for details.
```

... have a look at :

- http://www.saturnflyer.com/blog/jim/2010/06/24/rack-cache-on-heroku-with-memcached
- http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2011/06/03/heroku-celadon-cedar-review
- http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing yesterday with a cedar setup with a 4 worker unicorn in a single dyno vs the same app on a traditional single dyno - I actually found the traditional single dyno was marginally more performant on my tests between 10 and 50 users.